# How to build interaction for LightFM fit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recommendation-engine, lightfm

I want to train LightFM with Dataframe shown below.

| FromUserID | Title | PostID | Views | Likes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cricket | 34 | 12 | 8 |
| 6 | Mobile | 37 | 11 | 6 |
| 3 | tv | 34 | 8 | 5 |
| 5 | WTC final | 30 | 6 | 5 |

I already trained the model with Views column (which is working fine) but also want to add Likes column. I have seen lot of examples, however I'm still not able to understand how to train model based on dataframe I have.

Below are the code snippets I tried so far,

```
x = actual_topreviews.pivot_table(index='FromUserID', columns='PostId', values='Views')
xNan = x.fillna(0)
        
interaction = sp.csr_matrix(xNan.values)
hybridModel = LightFM(loss='warp-kos')
hybridModel.fit(interaction, epochs=30)
```

```
user_x=3
n_users, n_items = interactions.shape
scores = pd.Series(model.predict(user_x, np.arange(n_items)))
```

How can I train the model with both Views and Likes column?

Any suggestions or code snippets to help my understanding would really be appreciated. thank you